# In what order does `git log` show commits with same timestamp?

Tags: git, timestamp, git-commit, git-log

Look at this:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph
*   c3f035c (HEAD -> master) added files
|\  
| * df07f9e (alt) Add Z
| * 85d52b4 Add Y
| * cb54ba0 Add X
* | 0ee077f Add E
* | d968ccf Add D
* | b0777d7 Add C
|/  
* a0be85a Add B
* bb35288 Add A
```

^ That shows them in the order that they were committed.

But without --graph, the output is so confusing:

```
$ git log --oneline
c3f035c (HEAD -> master) added files
df07f9e (alt) Add Z
85d52b4 Add Y
cb54ba0 Add X
0ee077f Add E
a0be85a Add B
d968ccf Add D
bb35288 Add A
b0777d7 Add C
```

Why does it show C last? And A and B apart from each other?

the git log man page says that --graph implies --topo-order which makes it print all children before any parents, which is what i understand.

It also says that the default is reverse chronological order, so the commits are shown in the order that they happened, but C wasnt commited before A, how could that even be possible?

Could the problem be that A..E all have the same commit timestamp?
(CommitDate: Thu Mar 9 19:15:54 2023 +0200)

Comment: the reason why they have the timestamp is because i created them in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Add `--date-order` to defend against oddball timestamp punning like this, that does extra ancestry checking.

What's going on in your listing is, after it lists the merge it sees two ancestors, Z and E. Z's newer so it lists it and adds its ancestors. The newest is Y, repeat then X, repeat, now its candidates are E (still there) and B (added behind E since it's not newer), and so forth.